# Should sitemap requests load quickly?

Tags: performance, sitemap

Given the fact that the only clients accessing a sites' sitemaps are search engine spiders, does it make any sense to make these sitemap requests load quickly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried over such things, you can always choose to compress them (.gz) - that minimizes load a lot since compressed XML sitemap files are much smaller.

Comment: Tom that's a good suggestion. Unfortunately the bottleneck is not in the uploading process but in the generating. We have a complex db query that gets run to generate a new sitemap each time. It's very dynamic and changes daily.

Comment: Can't you just updated it once every over and cache it? Is it a news sitemap? (Since it changes so often)